# Function "merge_eurostat_geodata" not available in Eurostat Version 3.3.52

Tags: r, gis

Using the actual eurostat release via install.packages("eurostat") and library(devtools)
install_github("ropengov/eurostat") after calling merge_eurostat_geodata i get the error message:
Error in merge_eurostat_geodata..., : could not find function "merge_eurostat_geodata"

Does "merge_eurostat_geodata" not exist anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not

- `merge_eurostat_geodata` was in version 3.1.5 (August 2017) as shown at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/eurostat/versions/3.1.5
- but was not in version 3.2.1 (May 2018) as shown at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/eurostat/versions/3.2.1 and is not in the current release version 3.3.5
- Your question was raised four days ago as [Issue 146](https://github.com/rOpenGov/eurostat/issues/146)
- You can find the [old source for 3.1.5](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/eurostat/eurostat_3.1.5.tar.gz) but I would guess somebody removed the function for a reason, so that may or may not work